# How can I go through all ids and sum all copies of IDs scores together to one ID?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do something like a sports scoreboard for a school project but I ran into problem where I'm trying to add the game score to one big leaderboard but I have a problem. Since I wanna make it fully automatic. 
I wanna make it loop through all IDs and count them all to their own ID.

From this

```
+-----+-------+--+
| ID  | Score |  |
+-----+-------+--+
| 1   | 25    |  |
| 2   | 10    |  |
| 3   | 21    |  |
| 1   | 25    |  |
| 2   | 10    |  |
| 3   | 21    |  |
+-----+-------+--+
```

To this

```
+-----+-------+--+
| ID  | Score |  |
+-----+-------+--+
|  1  |    50 |  |
|  2  |    20 |  |
|  3  |    43 |  |
+-----+-------+--+
```

I've tried some I loops but havent gotten any of them working! And also tried to use Where ID = ID but it just counts all together

```
SELECT SUM(`Score`) FROM `Scores` WHERE `ID` = '1";
```

Comment: I've removed the C# tag as I can't see that the C# part is relevant - there certainly isn't any C# in the question.

Comment: I'd also suggest clarifying your question a bit - "count them all to their own ids" isn't very clear. I'm assuming you mean "sum the scores for each ID" given the example. Likewise the title talks about summing IDs - but you're summing the scores *for* each ID, not summing the IDs themselves. I'm not saying this just to be picky - not only will a better question be better received, but taking time to phrase your question carefully is also likely to help you solve it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to *group* by ID, and then sum within the group:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Score) AS Score FROM Scores GROUP BY ID
```